# Pandas: Add a column of list of values from other columns based on an index list in another column

Tags: python, pandas

This is the original data frame, where group contains list of index values of group which each person belongs to.

```
        Name           Group
0       Bob            [0, 1]
1       April          [0, 1]
2       Amy            [2, 3]
3       Linda          [2, 3]
```

This is what I would like to have, I want to create lists of name values for each group and add them back to the df by index mapping of the df with group list values

```
        Name           Group          Group_Name
0       Bob            [0, 1]         [Bob, April]       
1       April          [0, 1]         [Bob, April]
2       Amy            [2, 3]         [Amy, Linda]
3       Linda          [2, 3]         [Amy, Linda]
```

I tried to create name lists using for loop and attach them back to the df based on index mapping, but it was really slow due to the data size.

Please advise if you have better ideas and thanks in advance!

Comment: _I tried to create name lists using for loop and attach them back to the df based on index mapping, but it was really slow due to the data size._ Please provide a [mcve]. Is a DataFrame even the appropriate data structure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use

```
s=df.Group.map(tuple)
df['Group_Name']=df.groupby(df.Group.map(tuple)).Name.agg(list).reindex(s).values
df
    Name   Group    Group_Name
0    Bob  [0, 1]  [Bob, April]
1  April  [0, 1]  [Bob, April]
2    Amy  [2, 3]  [Amy, Linda]
3  Linda  [2, 3]  [Amy, Linda]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Group')['Name'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Group_Name')
```

use groupby to group on the column of interest and then apply list to every group

Comment: this would not work if the index did not match... for example Bob [2,3] instead [0, 1]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['Group_Name']=df['Group'].explode().map(df['Name']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)

    Name   Group    Group_Name
0    Bob  [0, 1]  [Bob, April]
1  April  [0, 1]  [Bob, April]
2    Amy  [2, 3]  [Amy, Linda]
3  Linda  [2, 3]  [Amy, Linda]
```

alternative without `explode`

```
df['Group_Name'] = (pd.DataFrame(df['Group'].tolist())
                      .stack().map(df['Name']).groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Group'].map(lambda group: [df['Name'].iloc[index] for index in group])
```