# Selecting DataFrame values based on column of indices in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I created a code that gets values of df based on list of indices in another column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'myvalues': [11, 13, 0, -1, 10, 14], 'neighbours': [[1,2],[0,2,3],[0,1,3],[1,2,4],[3,5],[4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['neighboring_idxs'] = df['neighbours']+pd.Series(([[x] for x in df.index.values])) 
df['neighboring_myvalues'] = df.apply(lambda row: df.myvalues.values[row.neighboring_idxs], axis=1)
```

Result is:

```
   myvalues neighbours neighboring_idxs neighboring_myvalues
0        11     [1, 2]        [1, 2, 0]          [13, 0, 11]
1        13  [0, 2, 3]     [0, 2, 3, 1]      [11, 0, -1, 13]
2         0  [0, 1, 3]     [0, 1, 3, 2]      [11, 13, -1, 0]
3        -1  [1, 2, 4]     [1, 2, 4, 3]      [13, 0, 10, -1]
4        10     [3, 5]        [3, 5, 4]         [-1, 14, 10]
5        14        [4]           [4, 5]             [10, 14]
```

However on large dataset using `apply` is really time-consuming. Is there a smarter way to achieve the same `df['neighboring_myvalues']`, without using `apply`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Add a column of list of values from other columns based on an index list in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218872/pandas-add-a-column-of-list-of-values-from-other-columns-based-on-an-index-list)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's faster but you can try to explode your list of list:

```
df['neighboring_myvalues'] = (
    df.explode('neighboring_idxs').reset_index()
      .assign(vals=lambda x: df.loc[x['neighboring_idxs'], 'myvalues'].tolist())
      .groupby('index')['vals'].agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   myvalues neighbours neighboring_idxs neighboring_myvalues
0        11     [1, 2]        [1, 2, 0]          [13, 0, 11]
1        13  [0, 2, 3]     [0, 2, 3, 1]      [11, 0, -1, 13]
2         0  [0, 1, 3]     [0, 1, 3, 2]      [11, 13, -1, 0]
3        -1  [1, 2, 4]     [1, 2, 4, 3]      [13, 0, 10, -1]
4        10     [3, 5]        [3, 5, 4]         [-1, 14, 10]
5        14        [4]           [4, 5]             [10, 14]
```